# How does increment_by of a PostgreSQL sequence work with the allocationSize of Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I've set up a test application with Hibernate, PostgreSQL and Spring and I keep running into this inexplicable error. I hope that somebody here can shed some light on the issue.

My entity looks like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "something")
public class Something {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "somethingGen", sequenceName = "something_id_seq", allocationSize = 30)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "somethingGen")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    public Something() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", Something.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("id=" + id)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I created a Spring Data Repository, inserted five entries and fetched them back:

```java
System.out.println("starting...");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    repository.save(new Something());
}

repository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
```

The first time I start this code it works almost as expected:

```
Something[id=1]
Something[id=2]
Something[id=3]
Something[id=4]
Something[id=5]
```

The second time however I end up with this exception: `org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [something_id_seq] sequence is set to [30] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].`

So I inspected the sequence in the Postgres DB:

```
uat=# \d something_id_seq
      Sequence "public.something_id_seq"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value        
---------------+---------+---------------------
 sequence_name | name    | something_id_seq
 last_value    | bigint  | 1
 start_value   | bigint  | 1
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
 min_value     | bigint  | 1
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 32
 is_cycled     | boolean | f
 is_called     | boolean | t
```

This is the first problem. It seems like Hibernate is creating sequences with the wrong increment value. So I changed the increment_by value: `alter sequence something_id_seq increment 30`  and launched my code again and ended up with this output:

```
Something[id=1]
Something[id=2]
Something[id=3]
Something[id=4]
Something[id=5]
Something[id=901]
Something[id=902]
Something[id=903]
Something[id=904]
Something[id=905]
```

And now the sequence looks like this:

```
---------------+---------+---------------------
 sequence_name | name    | something_id_seq
 last_value    | bigint  | 31
 start_value   | bigint  | 1
 increment_by  | bigint  | 30
```

So it seems to me that the new id is calculated via `increment_by * allocation_size + last_value`, but I was expecting the new id to be 30 (`allocation_size * last_value`) since I suspected that `increment_by` and `allocationSize` would be the same thing because of the MappingException.

This leaves me with two questions:

1. I expected ids around 0, 30, 60, 90... and instead I ended up with ids around 1 and 900. The javadoc of SequenceGenerator states that allocationSize is `the amount to increment by when allocating sequence numbers from the sequence`. Does this mean `increment_by` and `allocationSize` are not the same thing? How do they tie together (e.g. why am I seeing a `MappingException`) and how do I achieve the behavior I expected?
2. The MappingException indicates to me that Hibernate is creating sequences with the wrong increment value. How do I get Hibernate to create the correct one?

I'm using Hibernate 5.4.2.Final and PostgreSql 9.6.12 and these settings:

```java
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(PostgreSQL9Dialect.class.getName());
hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
```

I suspect that the issue might be somewhere with the HiLo generator but for the life of me I can't figure it out:

```
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred=hilo
hibernate.schema_update.unique_constraint_strategy=RECREATE_QUIETLY
```

Answer (score 0):

`increment_by` and `allocationSize` need to be of the same size. However unless you have a distributed insert-heavy system, you should just go with the default `increment_by` of 1, and use  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

You probably end-up with the jump to 900, because of various threads reserving the id, but then failing an insert. I had that problem. Now I insert with `IDENTITY`.

As for the MappingException, the `something_id_seq` sequence is created automatically by postgres because the PostgreSQL dialect uses `serial` or `bigserial` when creating the table. See [PostgreSQL81IdentityColumnSupport](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.4.2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/identity/PostgreSQL81IdentityColumnSupport.java). Perhaps it should be considered a bug that Hibernate doesn't alter the sequence to the `allocationSize`, and you can report it.

Comment: I'm not using any threads. The sample code above is actually the entire code of the application. I don't think that the sequence is generated by PostgreSQL because the create statement is being logged and if I'm not using HiLo then the  increment is correct.